# Why I get error whenever I try to publish the project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis

I use visual studio 2013.

I always get this error when I try to publish my project:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

Here how looks my publish files settings:

[image]

When I make build or debugging the solution in visual studio I don't get any errors and evrythings works fine!

I get into the troubleshoot only when i try publish the project.\

Any idea why I get error when I pushlsh the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971052

You need to clean the cache.